# Cascade On Delete in Grails GORM MongoDB is a bug?

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-2.0

I'm using GORM with MongoDB in Grails 2.3.9. According to http://spring.io/blog/2010/07/02/gorm-gotchas-part-2/, there must be no cascade on delete. But the fact is, when a user is deleted, all his roles are also deleted.

Is it a bug in GORM for MongoDB?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to clear the collection before deletion:

```
user.roles.clear()
user.delete()
```

But, this is just a workaround, I think.